# What effect or plugin is this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

As the name of this type of example of parallax, or the name of the plugin?
Also I'm looking for more examples with that kind of effect, would greatly appreciate if you have any tutorial too.

http://www.grad.uottawa.ca/RapportAnnuel/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's just css3 transition and trasnformations.

You can see [example there](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/filters/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like custom JS, if you view the source you will find a file here http://www.grad.uottawa.ca/RapportAnnuel/assets/js/data/lang.js?v=4

All of the content of the page is in this file.

Comment: It's a translation script isn't it?